# If $G$ has a unique maximal normal subgroup $M$ and $G'< G$, then $G/G'$ is a cyclic $p$-group, for some prime $p$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

If $G$ has a unique maximal normal subgroup $M$ and $G'< G$, then $G/G'$ is a cyclic $p$-group, for some prime $p$? I think the idea is going through the Frattini, but I'm not seeing the argument.

Comment: No, it is not true. $G$ could be cyclic of any prime power order.

Comment: Did you perhaps mean that $G/M$ is cyclic of order $p$ (this is true)?

Comment: As I said, any cyclic group of prime power order is a counterexample.

Comment: No, in that case $G' = \{1\}$.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I'm saying cyclic $p$-group.

Comment: Ok, now the statement is correct. Hint: $G/G'$ has a unique maximal subgroup. Show that this condition is enough to conclude that a group is cyclic of prime power order.

Comment: I saw it. Dumb question. Sorry...

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, oh, I misread. Will delete my comment then. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $G$ has a unique maximal normal subgroup and $G' < G$ then $G/G'$ has a unique maximal subgroup (since all subgroups of $G/G'$ correspond to normal subgroup of $G$).

If a group has a unique maximal subgroup, it is cyclic (any element not in that maximal subgroup will generate the group), and it must have prime power order (as it will have a subgroup of index any prime dividing the order, and any such subgroup is clearly maximal. And it is easy to check that the infinite cyclic group has an infinite number of maximal subgroups).

Comment: Your second paragraph is an excellent answer to Roman's **Exercise 4.4** of his *"Fundamentals of Group Theory: An Advanced Approach"*: "Show that if $G$ has a *unique* maximal subgroup $M$, then $G/M$ is cyclic of prime order". Thank you.